# How can an application installed via wine be enabled to access NTFS partitions automatically and quickly?

Tags: wine, ntfs

I am quite new to Ubuntu. I have found the  solution that comes closest to my above-mentioned problem in the admirable answers to the question "Why can an application installed using Wine not access NTFS partitions?" The procedure as I have understood from those answers is as follows:

1. Mount the desired partition.
2. Go to Wine configuration, then to 'Drives', click 'Z:', then 'Browse', click '+' beside 'media', then '+' beside your user name, and you find your desired partition.

This works. Now my question is:

**Is there any way to automate and shorten the process?**

One of the answers there says I can add drive letters to point directly to it. Maybe this contains the answer I am looking for but, if so, will someone please explain it more fully?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that NTFS are not automatically mounted as executable partitions.  You need to mount it as a "ntfs-3g" partition.  I'm not smart enough to know what the difference is, but changing it allowed me to better control file permissions (e.g. executable).

In your /etc/fstab:
     [partition] [/path/to/mount/] ntfs-3g defaults,auto,uid=1000,gid=home,umask=002 0 0

It's explained better at the Ubuntu Forums: [Mount NTFS partitions...](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604251)

Good luck!